# Why is this class not immutable?

Tags: java, list, reference, immutability

I had a Java interview today and I was asked to create an immutable class named Person and I was given a skeleton with some parameters: age, name, etc. I created the below class:

```
final class Person {
  private final int age;
  private final String name;
  private final List<String> petNames;


  public Person(int a, String n, List<String> p) {
    this.age = a;
    this.name = n;
    this.petNames = p;
  }

  int getAget() {
    return this.age;
  }

  String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  List<String> getPetnames() {
    return this.petNames;
  }

}
```

I was told that it is not complete because by performing the below sequence of code, you prove that it is not immutable:

```
int x = 3;
String name = "Alex";
List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();
Person p1 = new Person(x, name, ls);
```

The hint I was given is that it is related to the list and that I should change sth in the constructor. But I really do not know why and I do not really understand what is wrong.

Can anyone explain me what should be added and why ? Maybe I did not understand completely immutability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume they asked you to keep an immutable copy of the given pet collection.

```
this.petNames = List.copyOf(p);
```

Otherwise, you would still be able to modify the pets of a person.

```
p1.getPetnames().add("newPet");
```

You shouldn't be bothered with what will happen to `ls`, but you should take care of what you can do with `p1`.

1. You make a copy to stop worrying whether the input is going to be changed sometime later.
2. You make the collection immutable, which, along with the 2 final plain fields, makes the class immutable.

Comment: Where does `ImmutableList` come from?

Comment: @smac89 https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html

Comment: Cool. I thought it was a new addition to Java.

Comment: @smac89 I don't have a new Java at hand, but I assume there is already something similar to Guava's

Comment: @smac89 yes, it's List.copyOf (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection))

Answer (score 5):

To make list immutable, I believe you should use

```
       this.petnames=  ImmutableList.copyOf(p);
```

or

```
     this.petnames  = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(p));
```

In java 9, you can use copyOf() method to create immutable list

```
 this.petnames = List.copyOf(p)
```

If you return this  then its not possible to add or remove elements to it. However, they can be get elements out of it.

Comment: Just modify your line to `this.petnames= Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(p));`

Comment: @SomeDude Thanks for suggestion. Updated.

Comment: Note that Java 9's `List.of` does not have an implementation that takes a `Collection` and returns an immutable list of the contents of the collection

Comment: See this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61510584/why-this-class-is-not-immutable/61510653?noredirect=1#comment108809379_61510653). It should be `List.copyOf`